# Renumber element in perm matrix MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a 1 x 9 matrix:

```
D = [6 5 2 9 8 4 3 1 7];
```

But I want to renumber it from 1 - 9 to 4 - 12. So at the end, I will have something like this

```
D = [9 8 5 12 11 7 6 4 10]
```

Is there any possible way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

Just add 3 to your vector:

```
D = [6 5 2 9 8 4 3 1 7];

E = D + 3;
```

This results in

```
E =

     9     8     5    12    11     7     6     4    10
```